# How can an object have two different classes in R?

Tags: r, integer, double, numeric

The class *numeric* includes sub-classes *integer* and *double*. The interesting thing is that the class of a variable depends on the way it is initialised. For example:

```
x <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1)
y <- rep(0:1, c(5,5))

x
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
y
# [1] 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1

class(x)
# [1] "numeric"
class(y)
# [1] "integer"

identical(x,y)
# [1] FALSE
```

My question: why does R not coerce `x` in the example to class integer? I think it would make more sense to do so as `x` is an `integer` and a `numeric` vector, but a `numeric` vector is not necessarily a vector of integers. Hence, coercing `x` to be of the integer class might be more intuitive, at least for me. Am I missing something?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you type a `0` R understands this as a numeric (double). An integer has to be typed as `0L`. And of course, `:` is documented to return integer values "if `from` is integer-valued and the result is representable in the R integer type".